# Different size filters in the same layer with Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am taking a class in Udemy about `Tensorflow 2.0` and applying it to an image dataset. Anyways - the typical convolutional layer in the class code base looks like this:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
```

Is it possible to add multiple filter in the same layer say with size: `kernel_size=2`, `kernel_size=3`, `kernel_size=4`, and `kernel_size=5`?

Note that I would like to know how this is done in `TF2.0`

Edit: I am not constraining the problem t only conv2d layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the description of the kernel size arguments for Conv2D layer mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D) you cannot add multiple filters with different Kernel size or strides.

Also, Convolutions with Kernels of different sizes will produce outputs of different height and width.
The general formula for output size assuming a symmetric kernel is given by

> (X−K+2P)/S+1

- Where X is the input Height / Width
- K is the Kernel size
- P is the zero-padding
- S is the stride length

So assuming you are keeping zero paddings and stride same you cannot have multiple kernels with different sizes in Conv2D layer.

You can, However, use the [tf.keras.Model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model) API to use Conv2D multiple times on the same input and then either crop or use zero paddings to match the dimensions of the different outputs before stacking them.

For eg.

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(H,W,))
x1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3)(inputs)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=5)(inputs)
#match dimensions (height and width) of x1 or x2 here 
x3 = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)[x1,x2]
```

Use either [Zeropadding2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ZeroPadding2D) or [Cropping2D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Cropping2D) for matching dimensions.

Comment: This guy here claims to have mutliple width filters in the same layer - If I understand correctly: http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/ There is a link to the code in the page. I haven't figured it out yet. Having multiple layers it is not the same thing as having multiple filters with all the features - I would think.

Comment: in the code from the link I provided - if you look in the "train.py" - the default value (in the flags) for filters sizes is "3,4,5"...

Comment: What this guy has done is similar to what I suggested. Quoting him, "Remember that we use filters of different sizes. Because each convolution produces tensors of different shapes we need to iterate through them, create a layer for each of them, and then merge the results into one big feature vector." The only difference is that he uses max-pooling instead of cropping or zero-padding before concatenating. if you are not restricted to Conv2d you can use his method as well.